# Is a blood analyst's salary enough to pay rent for two houses and other expenses in Miami?

Tags: realism, dexter

In *Dexter*, Season 4, Dexter keeps two houses, one of his old one for secret works and one for Rita and his children. Similarly in Season 5, He returns to his old house but still keep's Rita's house for Lumen. So is this possible in Miami to hold two houses on rent on the salary of a blood analyst? Dexter has other expenses too like maintaining killing rooms/equipment/killing costume , expensive cars,boat, nanny's salary  etc. etc.

Comment: Not to mention a full time nanny.

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip here. But, IIRC, the flat (which he used to share with Deb) was inherited from Harry along with the boat. Rita's house is in her name. So there's no question of rent. He doesn't really own expensive cars either; his kill rooms are usually abandoned buildings and such. He might also have other sources of income.

Comment: @coleopterist if you are blood analyst/ full time psycho killer/single father then you left no time for other source of income.

Comment: @coleopterist he gifted a car to rita and even bought one for himself from a killer/car dealer.

Comment: @coleopterist Rita leaves her old house during marriage days to a bigger house with dexter. Rita even doesn't have enough money. Even she loosed her old job. And are you sure that dexter's house is Inherited? I mean it's never mentioned or i missed something.

Comment: quick google search, found a page on real life blood analysts, rookie analysts start off around the range fo $40k and senior (like dexter) can earn anywhere from $80k to $160k. I'd say he'd be in the high range of his salary, enough to afford the condo, boat and car. Also up until Season 5(?) he had no dependant children, so when he did have a dependant child, I assume the government would give him some kind of tax credits. Not being from America, not sure of the laws for that.

Comment: In addition to above, he sold his biological fathers' house in season 1, so he would have had at least a good $100k cash in hand from the sale.

Comment: @Jared opps missed the biological father's house.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found information ([Source](http://www.ehow.com/info_8468172_salary-blood-splatter-analyst.html)) on the net containing salary ranges for "Blood Analsyts".

- A rookie can start off from a $40,000 mark
- A Senior (like Dexter) can earn anywhere from $80,000 to $160,000

In addition to this, Dexter sold his biological fathers' house in season 1, from which I would guess he would get at least $100,000 cash in hand.

I also noted a comment passed by Angel Batista in Season 2 when they were trying to catch the "Bay harbour Butcher"

> that Coral Cove is still affordable on a cops' salary.

Which is where Dexter kept his boat, while not hard evidence, but does conclude that where he kept his boat is one of the cheaper harbours.

Lastly, while conjecture information, up until Season 4 he wasn't the legal guardian of Ritas' children and had no dependant children himself yet, so when he did have dependant children, I assume he would be eligible for government paid tax credits. Not being from America, not sure of the laws for that